# Push apart TableViewCells while dragging over them. (Similar to UITableViewCellReorderControl)

Tags: uitableview, drag-and-drop, placeholder

I want to have a similar functionality like we have with the UITableViewCellReorderControl from the UITableViewCell, but as far as I know I cant use the reordercontrol.

I have implemented Drag & Drop for multiple UITableViews. I can Drag a cell from any TableView to any other. Drag & Drop does work so far. Now I want to push the cells apart when I'm dragging an object over 2 cells, just like Apple does this in Tableviews or when you reorder your apps (the place where you might drop gets empty to indicate the droplocation).

The solutions I thought about are:
1. Insert a placeholder image at the droplocation (this is not so good as I have to sync with CoreData all the time)
2. Change the height of the cell to simulate empty space below it.

I dont think that are the best solutions.